# The single differential equation of Maxwell

Tags: quaternions

Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion):

> [...] Ludwik Silberstein, who used a potential function of one quaternion
> variable to express Maxwell's equations in a single differential
> equation.

What's the equation here?

Comment: Wikipedia cites (notes related to) Silberstein's [Theory of Relativity](https://books.google.com/books?id=K91FAQAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), which is available for free in searchable form.